# How to get heatmap picture response from API DAHUA CAMERA?

Tags: go, ip-camera

I'm making an app that sends data from the DAHUA camera to a specific server. I need information from the camera heat map. In the API guide it is stated to access the URL as follows:

```
http://192.168.1.108/cgi-bin/heatMap.cgi?action=getPicByTime&channel=1&StartTime=2022-05-25%2000:00:00&EndTime=2022-05-30%2023:59:59
```

but the data I get is a HeatMap.CGI file. Whereas in the manual the response is

> Content-Type: application/binarytet-stream
> Content-Length:

Any one has implement Get Heat Map Information ?

Comment: The problem here seems to be that your cgi-bin folder is not set up correctly, and/or your heatMap.cgi is not executable.

Comment: Thanks. For API people counting and snapshot image, it works as it should, only the heatmap and faces recognition parts don't work. I will try to ask the vendor who did the installation to check if it is appropriate.

Comment: I've updated the camera firmware version, but still no change regarding heat map API

Comment: Could you tell me where I can find the API guide manufacturer dahua ? @at.fajar please?